# Прикрепление динамического объекта к статическому

Tags: unity3d, 3dsmax

Прошу помощи т. к. не нахожу информацию. Ткните что почитать или что гуглить (или видео-урок). У меня есть модель с анимациями в 3dsmax. Мне нужно чтобы в `unity` у меня отображалась моделька (это башня с пушками) но в зависитмости от действий пользователя у нее была пушка вида, которого он выберет.

Так вот вопрос в том как это вообще организовывается?

Мои предположения:

1) Рисую башню в 3dsmax

2) Рисую 3 пушки в нем же

3) Переношу их в `unity` и в скрипте управляю

Отсюда вытекает вопрос: как прицепить пушку именно туда, куда нужно?

Comment: проще всего создать  модель, в которой будет все 3 пушки, и 2 отключать, правда нужно чтобы они были отдельными мешами

Comment: Самый очевидный способ - сделать из каждой башни префаб, вручную подогнать ее `Transform` и просто сохранить эти значения каким-либо образом, например, сериализовать в скрипте на каждом префабе-пушке.